# Access Context for Handler Enablement

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have an editor with multiple `TableViewer`s, so I can't just use the `ISelectionService` to access the currently active selection.

To work around this issue my editor uses `ToolItem#setData` after the creation of the table:

```
    final IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    final IMenuService menuService = (IMenuService) window.getService(IMenuService.class);
    final ToolBarManager manager = new ToolBarManager(new ToolBar(parent, SWT.NONE));
    menuService.populateContributionManager(manager, TOOLBAR_URI);
    manager.update(true);

    for (final ToolItem item : manager.getControl().getItems()) {
        item.setData(TABLE_VIEWER, myTableViewer);
    }
```

So that the handler can access the data like this:

```
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    final Widget toolItem = ((Event) event.getTrigger()).widget;
    final TableViewer myTableViewer = (TableViewer) toolItem.getData(TABLE_VIEWER);
    // do magic...
    return null;
}
```

This is all good and well, but now the problem arises when I want to enable / disable the handler based on the selection, e.g. disable it when nothing is selected.

The usual path is to define something like that via *plugin.xml* and the tags `enabledWhen` and `activeWhen`. The problem is I can't access the viewer.

I figure the most likely scenario would be to get a `PropertyTester`, but they don't get any context of the command / handler they are attached too (since supposedly they might be attached to something entirely different).

That's why I'm fresh out of options.

How do I base the enablement of a handler on the surrounding GUI?

Comment: You can use the `ISelectionService` with multiple table viewers by implementing a custom `ISelectionProvider` that provides the selection from whichever table is active.